# Why my simple C server exits when the client closes connection?

Tags: c, sockets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* exit() */
#include <strings.h>    /* bzero(), bcopy() */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    bzero(&my_addr,sizeof my_addr);
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(9999);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    int res;
    res = bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&my_addr,sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));
    
    res = listen(sockfd,5);
    
    while (1) {     // shouldn't this while cycle "keep alive" the server to wait for new clients?
        struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
        bzero(&cli_addr,sizeof cli_addr);
        socklen_t cli_size = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
        int clisockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,&cli_size);

        while (1) {
            char buf[100] = "";
            int b_recv = recv(clisockfd, buf, 100, 0);
            printf("%d %d\n",sockfd,b_recv);
            printf("%s\n",buf);
            char string[] = "test";
            send(clisockfd,string,sizeof string,0))
        }
    }
}
```

If I test my server with netcat, if I close netcat the server exits. Why? Shouldn't the external while loop keep it alive? Why and how can I avoid that the server closes?

Comment: Almost all the functions you use can return with errors. You really need to check for that!

Comment: You never allow to leave the inner `while` loop. Therefore you either loop there forever or some event happens that not only breaks that loop but also terminates the whole program. If you want the outer loop to keep the server running, you must allow for some condition to break the inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check closely the server will be terminated with a `SIGPIPE` signal when you close the connection from the client-side.

It happens because you don't check for closed-connection events, and attempt to write to the closed connection.

When `recv` return `0` you should not attempt to write to the connected socket. Instead you should close the socket and break out of the inner `recv`/`send` loop.

```
while (1) {
    char buf[100] = "";
    int b_recv = recv(clisockfd, buf, 100, 0);
    printf("%d %d\n",clisockfd,b_recv);  // Print the connection socket instead
    if (b_recv <= 0) {
        // Error or closed connection
        close(clisockfd);
        break;  // Go back to the outer loop, wait for new connections
    }
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    char string[] = "test";
    send(clisockfd,string,sizeof string,0))
}
```